# Using QWebEngine to render an image

Tags: qt, headless-browser, qwebkit, qtwebengine

I'm looking to replace `QWebKit` with `QWebEngine` in my headless renderer.  I initialise the page with `load()` and connect a slot to `loadFinished()` to generate the final .PNG image.  This used to work fine with `WebKit` but fails with `QWebEngine`.

Code is as follows...

```
_webView = new QWebEngineView();

....

// Render the HTML to an image
QPainter painter(&image);
_webView->page()->view()->render(&painter);
painter.end();
```

I receive the following errors :

> "Asking for share context for widget that does not have a window handle"
>   "QOpenGLWidget: Cannot be used without a context shared with the toplevel".

Does anyone have an example of rendering a screen using `QWebEngine`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the answer from @wlalele helped, you do need to call view->show(), but that wasn't the only issue.  In the end I had to inherit from QWebEngineView and override the event filter to monitor for update requests..

```
bool CustomWebEngine::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::UpdateRequest)
    {
        emit updateFinished();
    }
}
```

Only after an UpdateRequest event has been received are you guaranteed to have access to the page in the view()->render function.

Comment: Hi Richard, Please can you give more information on how you solved this? We are banging our heads against a wall!

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem, I solved it by showing the QWebEngineView after the load.

Here is the example that helped me :
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#details

```
QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView(parent);
view->load(QUrl("http://qt-project.org/"));
view->show();
```

I hope it will help you