# How can I get paint events with QtWebEngine?

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I extended `QWebEngineView`.

```cpp
#ifndef MYQWEBENGINEVIEW_H
#define MYQWEBENGINEVIEW_H
#include <QWebEngineView>
class MyQWebEngineView : public QWebEngineView
{
public:
    MyQWebEngineView(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyQWebEngineView();
protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};
#endif // MYQWEBENGINEVIEW_H
```

But I can't get `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` called.

```cpp
#include "myqwebengineview.h"
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWidget>

MyQWebEngineView::MyQWebEngineView(QWidget *parent):QWebEngineView(parent)
{
    qDebug() << "MyQWebEngineView(" << parent << ")";
    qDebug() << "Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen: " << testAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen);
    //setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen, true);
}
MyQWebEngineView::~MyQWebEngineView()
{
}
void MyQWebEngineView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    qDebug() << "paintEvent(" << event << ")";
    QWebEngineView::paintEvent(event);
    //QWidget::paintEvent(event);

    qDebug() << event->rect();
    qDebug() << event->region();
}
```

Can anybody please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I'd dig into the source -- I don't expect QWebEngine to be painting itself via the normal `paintEvent` mechanism, as its rendering it's based on QtQuick 2 (and thus OpenGL)...

Comment: `QWebEngineView` doesn't reimplement `paint`. Short of it using an OpenGl overlay, it's remotely possible that all of the raster integration is done directly in `event`. Try hooking that instead and see if any paint events are coming.

Comment: @KubaOber Can you please explain `hooking that` part?

Comment: @JinKwon By hooking it's meant to install an event filter on the widget. Then you'll see if you catch any `QEvent::Paint`

Comment: @KubaOber I'm not familiar with Qt nor C++. Is [this](http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/showQtExample.php?key=QtInstallEventFilterExample&index=172) what you want me to try? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately the widget `QWebEngineView` does not catch almost any events (except mouse enter and exit, recently added keyboard events), for example see ["[QTBUG-43602] WebEngineView does not handle mouse events"](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43602).

Almost all events (like mouse move or paint) are handled by `QWebEngineView` child delegate of private type `RenderWidgetHostViewQtDelegateWidget` that is derived from `QOpenGLWidget`.

It is possible to catch new child of `QWebEngineView` of type `QOpenGLWidget` and to install on this child the event filter hook for all needed events.

That solution relies on undocumented structure of `QWebEngineView`. Thus it may be not supported by future Qt releases. However, it is usable for projects with current Qt versions. Maybe in the future some more convenient interface to catch `QWebEngineView` events will be implemented.

The following subclass of `QWebEngineView` implements that:

```
#ifndef WEBENGINEVIEW_H
#define WEBENGINEVIEW_H

#include <QEvent>
#include <QChildEvent>
#include <QPointer>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QPaintEvent>

class WebEngineView : public QWebEngineView
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QPointer<QOpenGLWidget> child_;

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev)
    {
        // emit delegatePaint on paint event of the last added QOpenGLWidget child
        if (obj == child_ && ev->type() == QEvent::Paint) {
            QPaintEvent *pe = static_cast<QPaintEvent*>(ev);
            // do something with paint event
            // ...
            // or just emit signal to notify other objects
            emit delegatePaint(pe);
        }

        return QWebEngineView::eventFilter(obj, ev);
    }

public:
    WebEngineView(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QWebEngineView(parent), child_(nullptr)
    {
    }

    bool event(QEvent * ev)
    {
        if (ev->type() == QEvent::ChildAdded) {
            QChildEvent *child_ev = static_cast<QChildEvent*>(ev);

            // there is also QObject child that should be ignored here;
            // use only QOpenGLWidget child
            QOpenGLWidget *w = qobject_cast<QOpenGLWidget*>(child_ev->child());
            if (w) {
                child_ = w;
                w->installEventFilter(this);
            }
        }

        return QWebEngineView::event(ev);
    }

signals:
    void delegatePaint(QPaintEvent*);
};

#endif // WEBENGINEVIEW_H
```

Child adding is caught by `WebEngineView::event`. The child pointer is saved and the event filter is installed on this child. On the child paint event the signal `WebEngineView::delegatePaint(QPaintEvent*)` is emitted in `WebEngineView::eventFilter`.

The signal `delegatePaint` is always emitted when the Web view is changed by some script or by highlighting of some web controls due to mouse hover or for any other reason.

Note that it is not the same as overriding `QWebEngineView::paintEvent`. In that way it is possible only to receive notification that something is changed.

So, it is possible to react on the event directly in `WebEngineView::eventFilter` or to connect to the signal `delegatePaint` to notify other objects about Web view repainting, for example see [QT QWebEngine render after scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467776/qt-qwebengine-render-after-scrolling/33576100#33576100)

Comment: This doesn't work in 5.9 anymore. Any ideas how to do something similar for 5.9?

Comment: I was able to make it "work" with 5.9.2 by checking if `child_ev->child()->metaObject()->className()` is equals to `"QtWebEngineCore::RenderWidgetHostViewQtDelegateWidget"`.

Answer (score 6):

My demand is disabling the mouse click. 
Follow Orest's answer, the "w" always is NULL in the Qt 5.9.3.

```
QOpenGLWidget *w = qobject_cast<QOpenGLWidget*>(child_ev->child());
```

So I modify the answer follow Orest. That is more suitable for Qt 5.9.x.

```
#ifndef CUSTOMWEBVIEW_H
#define CUSTOMWEBVIEW_H

#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEvent>

class CustomWebView : public QWebEngineView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomWebView(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR);

protected:
    bool event(QEvent* evt)
    {
        qDebug() << evt->type();

        if (evt->type() == QEvent::ChildPolished)
        {
            QChildEvent *child_ev = static_cast<QChildEvent*>(evt);
            childObj = child_ev->child();

            if (childObj)
            {
                childObj->installEventFilter(this);
            }
        }

        return QWebEngineView::event(evt);
    }

    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev)
    {
        if (obj == childObj
                && (ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress
                    || ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return QWebEngineView::eventFilter(obj, ev);
    }

private:
    QObject *childObj = NULL;
};

#endif // CUSTOMWEBVIEW_H
```