# QT QWebEngine render after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qt5, qtwebengine

Saving an image of a webpage with a WebEngineView works fine, but when I want to scroll and save another image, the resulting image does not show the website has been scrolled (it shows the top of the webpage).

My question is: how do I scroll down in the QWebEngineView then save a screen shot that shows the correctly scrolled webpage?

I take a screenshot at the top of the webpage, scroll down ~700 pixels, wait for a javascript callback to trigger which then takes another screenshot. The javascript and callback works fine (I observe the QWebEngineView scrolling).

```
    this->setScrollPageHandlerFunc([&] (const QVariant &result) {
        saveSnapshotScroll();
    });
    saveSnapshotScroll();
    view->page()->runJavaScript("scrollPage();",this->scrollPageHandlerFunc);
```

Screenshot code:

```
void MainWindow::saveSnapshotScroll()
{

QPixmap pixmap(this->size());
view->page()->view()->render(&pixmap);
pixmap.save(QString::number(QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()) + ".png");

}
```

Javascript:

```
function scrollPage()
{
    var y = qt_jq.jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    qt_jq.jQuery(window).scrollTop(y+708);
}
```

**UPDATE:**  I've found that if I put the saveSnapshotScroll() on a timer of ~100ms or more (i.e. wait 100ms to save the snapshot after scrolling), instead of taking the screenshot as soon as the page is scrolled, it works.  So there is some latency between the javascript callback when a scroll has been performed, and the rendering of the scrolled page.  I wouldn't call this a complete solution and thus why I'm only updating the post.  What I would really like is a callback from QT that says the rendered webpage has been updated in the screen buffer.  Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the callback of `runJavaScript` is triggered the script is finished. However, the window should be repainted (or at least prepared for repainting) to use `QWidget::render(&pixmap)`.

It seems that some paint event can be useful to detect repainting of the widget. Unfortunately the `QWebEngineView` does not catch almost any event (except mouse enter and exit, recently added unhandled keyboard events), for example see ["[QTBUG-43602] WebEngineView does not handle mouse events"](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43602).

Almost all events (like mouse move or paint) are handled by `QWebEngineView` child delegate of private type `RenderWidgetHostViewQtDelegateWidget` that is derived from `QOpenGLWidget`.

It is possible to catch new child of `QWebEngineView` of type `QOpenGLWidget` and to install on this child the event filter hook for all needed events.

That solution relies on undocumented structure of `QWebEngineView`. Thus it may be not supported by future Qt releases. However, it is usable for projects with current Qt versions. Maybe in the future some more convenient interface to catch `QWebEngineView` events will be implemented.

The following example implements that magic:

```
#ifndef WEBENGINEVIEW_H
#define WEBENGINEVIEW_H

#include <QEvent>
#include <QChildEvent>
#include <QPointer>
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QWebEngineView>

class WebEngineView : public QWebEngineView
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QPointer<QOpenGLWidget> child_;

protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev)
    {
        // emit delegatePaint on paint event of the last added QOpenGLWidget child
        if (obj == child_ && ev->type() == QEvent::Paint)
            emit delegatePaint();

        return QWebEngineView::eventFilter(obj, ev);
    }

public:
    WebEngineView(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QWebEngineView(parent), child_(nullptr)
    {
    }

    bool event(QEvent * ev)
    {
        if (ev->type() == QEvent::ChildAdded) {
            QChildEvent *child_ev = static_cast<QChildEvent*>(ev);

            // there is also QObject child that should be ignored here;
            // use only QOpenGLWidget child
            QOpenGLWidget *w = qobject_cast<QOpenGLWidget*>(child_ev->child());
            if (w) {
                child_ = w;
                w->installEventFilter(this);
            }
        }

        return QWebEngineView::event(ev);
    }

signals:
    void delegatePaint();
};

#endif // WEBENGINEVIEW_H
```

Child adding is caught by `WebEngineView::event`. The child pointer is saved and the event filter is installed on this child. On the child paint event the signal `WebEngineView::delegatePaint` is emitted in `WebEngineView::eventFilter`.

The signal `delegatePaint` is always emitted when the web view is changed by some script or by highlighting of some web controls due to mouse hover or for any other reason.

The signal is emitted from the event filter before actual execution of `QOpenGLWidget::paintEvent()`. So, it looks that it is needed to take page snapshot only after full paint is finished (maybe using asynchronous `Qt::QueuedConnection` connection). It appears that at this point in the event filter when `delegatePaint` is triggered because of the JavaScript the widget is ready for `render()`. However, it possible to receive the paint event for some other reason (for example due to window activation) and that may lead to the warning message:

> QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected

So, it is still better to use `Qt::QueuedConnection` to avoid such issues.

Now the trick is to use the event `delegatePaint` only once when the JavaScipt is finished. That part can be adjusted to actual requirements.

The page view can be repainted at any moment due to some scripts or loading new images. Let's assume that we need to capture the page how it looks after the script execution. So, it possible to connect `delegatePaint` signal to `saveSnapshotScroll` slot only in the script callback and disconnect that connection in `saveSnapshotScroll`. The following test generates snapshots in a loop for three different scroll positions. The similar snapshots are orginized by folders `0`, `1` and `2`:

```
void MainWindow::runJavaScript()
{
    // count initialized by 0
    if (++count > 1000)
        return;

    QString script = QString::asprintf("window.scrollTo(0, %d);", 708 * (count % 3));

    view->page()->runJavaScript(script,
        [&] (const QVariant&) {
            connect(view, &WebEngineView::delegatePaint,
                    this, &MainWindow::saveSnapshotScroll,
                    Qt::QueuedConnection);
        }
    );
}

void MainWindow::saveSnapshotScroll()
{
    disconnect(view, &WebEngineView::delegatePaint,
               this, &MainWindow::saveSnapshotScroll);

    QPixmap pixmap(view->size());
    view->render(&pixmap);
    pixmap.save(QString::number(count % 3) + "/" +
                QString::number(QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()) + ".png");

    runJavaScript();
}
```

In those cases when the event is trigged by some other window interaction it is possible to get wrong snapshot. If the window is not touched during script execution the result is correct.

---

To avoid handling of wrong paint events it is possible to compare Web view pixmap with previously saved image. If difference between those images is small it means that the current paint event should be skipped and it is needed to wait for the next paint event:

```
void MainWindow::saveSnapshotScroll()
{
    QSharedPointer<QPixmap> pixmap(new QPixmap(view->size()));
    view->render(pixmap.data());

    // wait for another paint event if difference with saved pixmap is small
    if (!isNewPicture(pixmap))
        return;

    pixmap->save(QString::number(count % 3) + "/" +
              QString::number(QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch()) + ".png");

    disconnect(view, &WebEngineView::delegatePaint,
               this, &MainWindow::saveSnapshotScroll);

    runJavaScript();
}

bool MainWindow::isNewPicture(QSharedPointer<QPixmap> pixmap)
{
    // initialized by nullptr
    if (!prevPixmap) {
        prevPixmap = pixmap;
        return true;
    }

    // <pixmap> XOR <previously saved pixmap>
    QPixmap prev(*prevPixmap);
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&prev);
    painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::RasterOp_SourceXorDestination);
    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, *pixmap);
    painter.end();

    // check difference
    QByteArray buf;
    QBuffer buffer(&buf);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    prev.save(&buffer, "PNG");

    // almost empty images (small difference) have large compression ratio
    const int compression_threshold = 50;
    bool isNew = prev.width() * prev.height() / buf.size() < compression_threshold;

    if (isNew)
        prevPixmap = pixmap;

    return isNew;
}
```

The above solution is just an example and it is based on tools provided by Qt. It is possible to think about other comparison algorithms. Also similarity threshold may be adjusted to specific case. There is a limitation of such comparison if scrolled view is very similar to the previous image (for example in case of long empty space).

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed-- this is a clever solution.  It doesn't work 100% of the time, but I think this is as good as I'm going to get until WebEngine supports this officially.  It does seem to work for most cases, however.  Thanks!

Comment: @mathieujofis I also found that during window interactions it is possible to get paint event from other source that comes before needed event. I updated the post by my test details and `Qt::QueuedConnection`. I also tried to connect `delegatePaint` and `saveSnapshotScroll` forever during initialization without disconnecting. As a result I have snapshots of each new page transformation.

Comment: @mathieujofis I do not like partial solutions. You can try additional comparison of current image with previously saved image to be sure that it is correct paint event. It works always for me even if I actively move mouse over the window and move the window to background/foreground. If it is needed you can adjust comparison threshold to your task.