# QT QWebEngineView : How to inject touch events (touchstart, touchmove, touchend)?

Tags: qt, qwebengineview

I would like to inject touch events such as "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend" into the QWebEngineView. Then, I should be able to capture the events in my html page running in the webview for example using jquery like below :

```
$(document).on("touchstart",function() {
  console.log("Touchstart");
});
```

I tried using QMouseEvents as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067680/qt-webengine-simulate-mouse-event) SO answer and it works. But not the QTouchEvents.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you try to accept touch events by setting `setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents, true);` in your mainwindow?

Comment: Yes. I did ! still doesn't work.

Comment: Here is my code snippet :

    QTouchEvent *touch = new QTouchEvent(QEvent::TouchBegin, Q_NULLPTR, Qt::NoModifier, Qt::TouchPointStates(), touchPoints);

    QCoreApplication::postEvent(eventsReciverWidget, touch);